# How to generate flipped text like this - ʍoႨɟɹәʌoʞɔɐʇs

Tags: scripting

I want to make a script which can flip the text upside down like if I type 
stackoverflow it should make it to - ʍoႨɟɹәʌoʞɔɐʇs.

Many sites do this like this one [link text](http://www.sherv.net/flip.html) and this one [link text](http://www.cheesygames.com/upside-down-text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript Code. It will be easy to convert this code to Java or C#

```
function flip() {
 var result = flipString(document.f.original.value.toLowerCase());
 document.f.flipped.value = result;
}

function flipString(aString) {
 var last = aString.length - 1;

 var result = new Array(aString.length)
 for (var i = last; i >= 0; --i) {
  var c = aString.charAt(i)
  var r = flipTable[c]
  result[last - i] = r != undefined ? r : c
 }
 return result.join('')
}

var flipTable = {
a : '\u0250',
b : 'q',
c : '\u0254', //open o -- from pne
d : 'p',
e : '\u01DD',
f : '\u025F', //from pne
g : '\u0183',
h : '\u0265',
i : '\u0131', //from pne
j : '\u027E',
k : '\u029E',
//l : '\u0283',
m : '\u026F',
n : 'u',
r : '\u0279',
t : '\u0287',
v : '\u028C',
w : '\u028D',
y : '\u028E',
'.' : '\u02D9',
'[' : ']',
'(' : ')',
'{' : '}',
'?' : '\u00BF', //from pne
'!' : '\u00A1',
"\'" : ',',
'<' : '>',
'_' : '\u203E',
';' : '\u061B',
'\u203F' : '\u2040',
'\u2045' : '\u2046',
'\u2234' : '\u2235'
}

for (i in flipTable) {
  flipTable[flipTable[i]] = i
}
```

Comment: No attribution for the snippet?